# Difference between Covalent and non-Covalent interactions

Tags: quantum-chemistry

It is a general concept that non-covalent interactions are a result of electrostatic interaction while covalent interactions arise due to sharing of electron density. This, however, is not true since I have myself performed one study ([link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12039-017-1304-4)) proving that hydrogen bonding does not consist purely of energy from electrostatic sources.

Another popular method to look at the same is to study the energetics, however, the energy of strong non-covalent interactions (like strong hydrogen bond) does fall in the range of covalent interactions and is sometimes enough to break some low-energy covalent interactions.

**Hence, I am willing to know about how to distinguish between a covalent and non-covalent interaction?**

I would prefer some answer in terms of wave-function and electron densities with proper reference.

Comment: As far as your first paragraph goes, it's a matter of nomenclature. Hydrogen bonds are partially covalent so they aren't really "non-covalent" - your categorisation isn't good.

Comment: For the gray areas between covalent and non-covalent interactions, see e.g. https://science.sciencemag.org/content/371/6525/160

Comment: This paper is also useful... 
 https://doi.org/10.1039/B704781A